# vim: how to concatenate different parts of a error line in "set efm="?

Tags: vim, format, concatenation

We have our lex/yacc generated compilers in our project, my build log is like this:

```
[2017-02-13 16:37:41.123456] [warning]  [1743]  [mysource/impl.cpp:25] Syntax warning ...
```

The format of this build error log is:

```
[timestamp] [info/debug/warning/error] [compiler pid] [filename/line] message
```

I've my .vimrc with this line:

```
let &errorformat = '[%.%#]%*[ \t][%t%*[A-Z]]%*[ \t][%n]%*[ \t][%f:%l]%m'
```

Well I can get with "vi -q builderror.txt" and show in quickfix window like:

```
mysource/impl.cpp|25 info 1743| Syntax warning
```

OK no problem.

### My requirement is: I wish to concatenate the error message with timestamp information like this:

```
mysource/impl.cpp|25 info 1743| Syntax warning [2017-02-13 16:37:41.123456]
```

Then that I can navigate all build errors and know the time taken on each compilation step.

So how show I "set efm=" or "let &errorformat="? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sato-katsura said, you must move the time stamp for Vim to pick it up as part of the `errorformat`.

Here is one way to do it on a UNIX-like system…

1. Change the `errorformat` in your `vimrc`:

   ```
   let &errorformat = '[%t%*[A-Z]]%*[ \t][%n]%*[ \t][%f:%l]%m'
   ```
2. Massage your `builderror.txt`:

   ```
   $ vim -q <(sed 's/^\(\[[^]]*\]\) \(.*\)/\2 \1/g' builderror.txt)
   ```

If you don't want to change `errorformat` globally you could…

- put that line in a local `exrc` at the root of your directory, see `:help 'exrc'`;
- put that line in a local `efm.txt` at the root of your directory and use it like so:

  ```
  $ vim --cmd "source efm.txt" -q <(sed 's/^\(\[[^]]*\]\) \(.*\)/\2 \1/g' builderror.txt)
  ```
- put all of that in simplistic bash script:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash

  [ $# -eq 1 ] && vim --cmd "let &errorformat = '[%t%*[A-Z]]%*[ \t][%n]%*[ \t][%f:%l]%m'" -q <(sed 's/^\(\[[^]]*\]\) \(.*\)/\2 \1/g' "$1")
  ```
- probably a dozen other solutions/workarounds…

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with `errorformat` alone.  You need to preprocess the errors to move the timestamps at the end before parsing.  How you can do that concretely depends on how you parse said errors.